# Storm, exception from Kafka while starting topology, Workers won't start?

Tags: apache-storm

I realize this is a little vague, but any advice as to how I can troubleshoot this would be very helpful.

My topology uses a `KafkaSpout`. When I start the topology I see the below exception and all my executors die. Then the worker tries to start again, the exception occurs, and the executors die. This continues with no resolution, the worker's uptime never exceeds a few seconds.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: null
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:538) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:359) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at kafka.message.Message.sliceDelimited(Message.scala:229) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at kafka.message.Message.payload(Message.scala:218) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.generateTuples(KafkaUtils.java:201) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.next(PartitionManager.java:131) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:141) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4654$fn__4669$fn__4698.invoke(executor.clj:565) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__458.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_11]
```

Comment: No idea. Might even be a bug... You should try to get an answer over Storm mailing list.

Comment: manually clearing the Kafka topic fixed this, but I don't have any explanation why. possibly the topic had some sort of "corrupted" message in it. but, even so, I would think the KafkaSpout would handle this more gracefully than throwing an exception and killing everything?